# How to "#define" struct field or struct name

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to do something like:

```
    int  desc = -1;
    if ( DB_DBM_HSEARCH == 1 )  {    desc = db->fd  }   else desc = db->dbm_pagf;
```

This is impossible because of a compiler error.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
   #define DESC db->fd     //and then
    int desc = DESC;
```

?

Comment: Both examples are missing a required `;`. The first example, within the `if` block. The second example after `int desc = DESC`

Comment: I can see missing semicolons in your code, but nothing else unusual that a compiler won't accept.

Comment: Now all works, no idea why I was getting this compiler error. I will try this on another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Though I think this would be a more suitable way to do it using macro functions (so you can change your variable names if you need to).  Assuming `DB_DBM_HSEARCH` [is a macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/mifluz/doc/doxydoc/db_8h-source.html):

```
/* conditionally define the macros */
#if DB_DBM_HSEARCH == 1
#  define DESC(db) (db)->fd
#else
#  define DESC(db) (db)->dbm_pagf
#endif

/* then to initialize */
int desc = DESC(db);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but don't use macros for this sort of thing, just use nicely named variables.